# Check when R session have been started?

Tags: r

Is there way to check when R session have been started ? In `interactive mode`, not necessary in `batch mode`.

Comment: Do you need to check this from within R?

Comment: @docendo discimus it would be great, but I suppose its impossible, so not, but lets wait, mayby there will be answer

Comment: Do you mean what time the session started?

Comment: What's your use case for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In windows you can try to see time of creation temp dir for `r-session`

`file.info(tempdir())$ctime`

Its only idea  and may be not always work

Comment: Nice. This works also on Linux and is "less invasive" than my solution. The problem is if for some reason the temp directory is modified, your line will report the time of the last modification.

Comment: @nicola In `?file.info`  "On Windows native file systems ctime is the file creation time (something which is not recorded on most Unix-alike file systems)." may be it work only for windows

Comment: @nicola Tried edit folder( add some files) `mtime` and `atime` changed , but `ctime` not

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right. I tried your line on Ubuntu and seemed to work for awhile. Then, the `ctime` changed for some reason.

Answer (score 7):

It won't work on the current sessions, but may (locally) work on future sessions. Edit/create a `.Rprofile` file in your home directory  and add these two lines:

```
.startedTime<-Sys.time()
.sessionTime<-function() Sys.time()-.startedTime
```

The lines in `.Rprofile` are executed at the beginning of the session. I choose names starting with a dot so they don't get returned by `ls()`. Next, start an R session and when you give:

```
.sessionTime()
```

it will return the elapsed time from the beginning of the session.

Comment: Exactly what I *would* have posted if I were awake 3 hrs ago :-)

Answer (score 7):

The `proc.time` function track times since R started (see help) which could be used as:

```
Sys.time() - proc.time()["elapsed"]
```

to find out when session started.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to the question.